# Keep an application running

Tags: c#, service

Hi all i have created a service based application which communicates with a pipe
the service application works until the windows application stops which contains the
pipe server code.

Comment: Please don't include tags in the title of your question.  Instead, use the tagging system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. You will have to merge this process in the code with whatever code you already have for your service. Replace the "PipeServiceName.exe" to whatever the name of the process is called. Also, this code checks every 5 seconds. You can change this by changing the 5000 number.

Without knowing more about how the "pipe" and the service interact with each other, its hard to put together a workflow.

```
private readonly ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private Thread _thread;

public MyService()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _thread = new Thread(MonitorThread)
    {
        IsBackground = true
    }
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    _shutdownEvent.Set();
    if (!_thread.Join(5000))
    {
        _thread.Abort();
    }
}

private void MonitorThread()
{
    while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(5000))
    {
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("PipeServiceName.exe");
        if (pname.Count == 0)
        {
             // Process has stopped. ReLaunch
             RelaunchProcess();
        }
     }
}

private void RelaunchProcess()
{
    Process p = new Process();

    p.StartInfo.FileName = "PipeServiceName.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = ""; // Add Arguments if you need them

    p.Start();
}
```